# How to change a custom field on form save

Tags: forms, 6

In the node type page I've added one Integer field "field_article_rejected".
When in rejected stated it contains 1.

**But when a registered user changes and "Saves" it I want to set the value of it to 0.**

Also the registered user does not have read/write permission on this field. But if needed I can give the user permission for this field but I'll hide it in "Display fields"

How to do it?

I'm working on Drupal-6.

To explain what I'm doing: I've created an article directory. So an user will log-in and create an article type of page. So now this page will be shown as "Submitted articles" block using views.

But as an admin when I reject it then I want this article to be shown under "Rejected Articles" block to the user. So I want to use field "field_article_rejected". When 0 it means user has sumbitted and when 1 then it means rejected by admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a custom module that will include hook_form_alter().   Something like this:

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'article_node_form') {
    global $user;

    if (in_array('admin', array_values($user->roles))) {
      //admin role is not a default role
      //do nothing
    }
    elseif (in_array('authenticated user', array(values($user->roles))) {
      //remove editable field and replace it with a label
      $form['article_field_rejected']['#access'] = FALSE;
      $form['article_field_rejected_label'] = array (
         '#type' => 'item',
         '#default_vale' =>  isset($field['article_field_rejected']['#value']) ? $field['article_field_rejected']['#value'] : '0',
    } 
    else {
     // For everyone else disable field and do not display it
     $form['article_field_rejected']['#access'] = FALSE;
    }     
}
```

If you don't replace the field with a label, then the use can still alter the value by editing the browser.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're already using the *Content permissions* module and have only enabled `edit field_article_rejected` to the appropriate role, let's use `content admin`.

Now, we're going to use the [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module to reset the field back to 0 each time the node is saved by a user that does NOT have the `content admin` role, most likely the owner.

**Label:** Reset article rejected
**Event:** Content is going to be saved

*Add a condition*

**Select condition to add:** User has role
**User:** Acting user
**Negate:** (checked)
**Select role(s):** content admin

*Add an action*

**Select an action to add:** Populate a field
**Content:** Saved content
**Field:** field_article_rejected
**Article rejected:** 0

It only takes 5 minutes to configure a rule. No custom module needed, no code whatsoever. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom module that implements [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_form_alter/6) within this you can target your form by `$form_id` then within that you can use something similar to below:

```
global $user
if (in_array('registered user', array_values($user->roles)) {
  $form['field_blah'][0]['value'] = 0;
}
```

Your `$form` structure may be different.